# Templete in App.vue doesn't show in index.html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using local `vue.js` These are my files.
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="res/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="res/vue-router.js"></script>
  <title>Vue</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app" ></div>
  <script type="module" src="App.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**App.js**

```
import Vue from './res/vue.js'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{foo}}
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  export default {
    name: 'App',
    data: function(){
      return{
        foo:'Hello vue'
      }
    }
  }
</script>


<style>

</style>
```

But my index.html shows nothing

Comment: `.vue` files need to be compiled.  You need to use the vue-cli + webpack if you want to use `.vue` files.

Comment: Can I use it on my android to run this application ?

Comment: I've never attempted so i'm not sure.  Your easiest way forward is to use in-dom templates or put your template as a string in the component in a .js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the Steven suggested you have to compile vue components.

If you dont want to do it that way, below is the the easiet way.

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      foo: 'Hello vue',
    };
  },
}).mount('#app');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

    <!-- <script src="res/vue-router.js"></script> -->
    <title>Vue</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">{{foo}}</div>
    <script type="module" src="App.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You probably need to `build` it with `vue-cli` to create a SPA(Single page Application) for your android application

Answer (score 1):

You mount your vue instance at the div node which id is "app", but i can't find the "#app" node, so you can resolve that by insert the "#app" node .

index.html:

```
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="App.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi is your import correct? from node_modules it should be `import Vue from 'vue'` and not `import Vue from './res/vue.js'` try it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).